# \underbrace function: How can two underbraces be on the same height?

Tags: positioning, size, underbrace

I am introducing a formula in my paper and would like to have two `\underbrace`s below two parts of the formula. Now it looks kind of odd, as the second `\underbrace` is way higher than the first. Do you have any ideas ho to fix it without needing to eliminate the fraction?

I print my code below:

```
\begin{equation}\label{eq:underbrace}
            x_{t} = \underbrace{\beta_{0} + \beta_{1} t + \gamma_{1} \cos(t * \frac{2\pi}{365})   +  \delta_{1} d_{t}}_{s_{t}}  + \underbrace{\epsilon_{t}}_{y_{t}}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use `\vphantom`s to achieve similar heights for constructions:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  x_t = \underbrace{
    \beta_0 + \beta_1 t + \gamma_1 \cos(t \times \frac{2\pi}{365}) + \delta_1 d_t
  }_{s_t} + 
  \underbrace{\epsilon_t \vphantom{\frac{2\pi}{365}}}_{y_t}
\]

\end{document}
```

I'd probably be inclined to drop the use of such a large (display) `\frac` and instead use:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\[
  x_t = \underbrace{
    \beta_0 + \beta_1 t + \gamma_1 \cos(2 \pi t / 365) + \delta_1 d_t
  }_{s_t} + 
  \underbrace{\epsilon_t \mathstrut}_{y_t}
\]

\end{document}
```